# Changing upload dir in a plugin regardless of post type

Tags: plugin-development, uploads

I read [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35657/how-to-add-more-upload-directories/) and found it really interesting. I tried to modify it a little to make it work if you have a *custom db table* and not a post type to rely on. So I tried to figure that out using `get_current_screen()` instead of `get_post_type()`.

In this example I wrote a plugin to register members and have the profile photos upload to the plugin dir just like in the original code. Although this doesn’t seem to work, the files are still saved in the regular `wp-content/uploads/` dir. Any ideas?

The plugin itself uses a simple form to save data to db and I also hooked the wp-uploader to upload and send the image url with the rest of the data.

```
function custom_upload_directory( $args ) {

$screen = get_current_screen();

// If the parent_base is members, upload to plugin directory
if ( $screen->parent_base == 'members' ) {
    $args['path'] = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . "uploads";
    $args['url'] = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . "uploads";
    $args['basedir'] = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . "uploads";
    $args['baseurl'] = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . "uploads";
}
return $args;
}
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'custom_upload_directory' );
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Typo: ' not is ‘

You have a weired Editor. You're simply using the wrong type of quotes:

- `“` should be `"`
- `‘` should be `'`

Here's the changed function:

```
function wpse43013_custom_upload_directory( $args ) 
{
    // If the parent_base is "members", upload to plugin directory
    if ( 'members' === get_current_screen()->parent_base )
        return wp_parse_args( $args, array_fill_keys(
             array( 'path', 'url', 'basedir', 'baseurl' )
            ,plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'uploads'
        ) );

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'wpse43013_custom_upload_directory' );
```

#### Debug

Normally that should throw an error. Be sure that you have set `WP_DEBUG` set to `TRUE`  inside your `wp-config.php` file when testing code inside a development environment.

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

On production sites you could also enable the error log (don't do this constantly and disable error display so errors are gracefully logged and not displayed to your users.

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
@ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );
```

See the [editing wp-config](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php) page for more info on defining configuration constants.

Comment: Oh sorry about that guys. I have the correct quotes, it just got weird when I copy+pasted the code. Which means that I still got something wrong with the function.

Comment: **Copy/Paste is nothing you should ever! do**. Just type it off the source bit by bit to make shure you have no copypasta errors. If they're displaying correctly, then your editor is fooling you.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry those got messed up and I should have read my question more thoroughly after posting. =/

Comment: Ok, so what do you get from the debug?

Comment: The only thing from the debug is: 
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: post_id in /var/www/sd1/htdocs/test/wp-admin/includes/media.php on line 1260

 - I get this notice even when the function is commented out.

Comment: @lepardman Did you add what Mark Duncan added to my Q? In this case you need to check your debug log file. It should be in your /wp-content folder.

Comment: Yep the notice is from the log file.

Comment: Wait a moment: If you get that error, than it's outside the scope of this Q. Please search and fix this error first.