# How to set an upload directory for each media type?

Tags: uploads

Is there a way I can set a custom upload folder for each media type? for example: .PNGs should be saved in uploads/png, .GIFs in upload/gifs

Answer (score 2):

**[More info added]. See below the code.**

```
//~ change upload dir
add_filter('upload_dir', 'choose_upload_dir');

//~ upload image
$upload = wp_handle_upload( $_FILES['your_form_input_name'], array('test_form' => false) );

//~ change upload dir back
remove_filter('upload_dir', 'choose_upload_dir');

function choose_upload_dir($upload) {
    //~ your file to upload
    $file_type = $_FILES['your_form_input_name']['type'];

    //~ switch between file types
    switch($file_type) {
        //~ if type is 'png' then upload subdir is '/png' and so on
        case 'image/png':
            $type_dir = '/png';
        break;

        case 'image/jpeg':
            $type_dir = '/jpg';
        break;

        default:
            $type_dir = '/others';
    }

    $upload['subdir'] = $upload['subdir'].$type_dir;
    $upload['path'] = $upload['basedir'].$upload['subdir'];
    $upload['url'] = $upload['baseurl'].$upload['subdir'];

    return $upload;
}
?>
```

**More info**: Casually I've stumbled upon useful plugin which allows you to setup different directories for your uploads: [Relocate Upload](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/relocate-upload/)

Comment: Any chance you're still out there listening to these comments, Max Yudin? I would love to get this code to work, but I get an error of "Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_handle_upload()". After a bit of research on the wp_handle_upload function I found some sample code on the [codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload) and added it to the start of your code: `if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
}`. The error goes away but still no luck w/ uploads being created in their own folder

Comment: Found an answer in a related question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25894/how-can-i-organize-the-uploads-folder-by-slug-or-id-or-filetype-or-author?lq=1