# Preview Image Path in Admin Section

Tags: images, filters, urls

So I have run into a little glitch. i have a custom path for uploads and it works. the files get saved to the right place, etc. The problem I have is the 'widget box' in the admin section. immediately after uploading and setting the uploaded image as the featured image, it show up in the preview, instead of 
`www.blog.com/blog/uploads/POST_ID/image_name.png`
it is showing

`www.blog.com/blog/uploads/image_name.png`
The path is broken. Again I am new to WP... is there a filter for the admin 'widget box's?

The path I get back is:
`<img width="266" height="145" src="http://mysite.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/image-350x192.png" class="attachment-266x266" alt="the title" title="the title">`

But where the image resides is:
`<img width="266" height="145" src="http://mysite.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/<POST_ID>/image-350x192.png" class="attachment-266x266" alt="the title" title="the title">`

I cant add an image because of my rep so far... it appears in the same column as `tags` and `categories` in the admin area. It is a custom `widget` for this theme.

**update**

```
    function media_upload_dir($upload) {
        if(!isset($_REQUEST['post_id']))
        return $upload;
$id = $_REQUEST['post_id'];
        if (isset($_REQUEST['post_id'])) {
            $upload['path']    = "/path/www/blog/wp-content/uploads/" . $id;
            $upload['url']     = "http://site.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/" . $id;
            $upload['basedir'] = "/path/www/blog/wp-content/uploads/" . $id;
            $upload['baseurl'] = "http://site.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/" . $id;
            if (!file_exists("/path/www/blog/wp-content/uploads/" . $id)) {
                mkdir("/path/www/blog/wp-content/uploads/" . $id, 0777);
            }
        }
        return $upload;
    }
    add_filter('upload_dir', 'media_upload_dir');
```

cheers.bo

Comment: What do you refer as the "widgets box"? Is it the Featured Image box? A screenshot could be useful. Also, is this path being printed or you see it when inspecting the html code?

Comment: yes the `featured image`!

Comment: But you can post a link to some screenshots somewhere else... What about the path, how are you checking it?

Comment: i added the path above. using firebug

Comment: How are you setting the custom upload paths? Your custom widget may need to be adapted accordingly.

Comment: it may not be getting the post id correctly

Comment: Where an how did you set a custom upload path

Comment: in the functions.php file of the theme. see edits above.

Comment: Ha! Finally the code!! I managed to make this work but I'm not sure if posting the solution here on in another question I found, where the scope of the question and the solution will be of better use. I mean, you are new to WordPress and to this Stack, and the way you are formulating the problem and describing it are making it difficult to edit your Question and making it beneficial for a broader audience. I see that you don't have the `Analytical` badge, awarded when you read the full FAQ... Stay tuned, I'll be back :)

Answer (score 2):

This is not a answer, is an extended comment with the [link to the solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/53895/12615).

First, while testing, one of my test sites wasn't showing the Featured Image uploaded to the folder `/wp-content/uploads/POST_ID/image_name.jpg`. Same problem as the OP.

*But*, it was not displaying *any path* to the image. And the bug was that the installation where I was testing is **full of hacks** (my main WPSE testing base). As soon as I went to a stable installation everything worked.

So, if your problem persist, do a full troubleshooting:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-33-master-list

Also, Robert, when asking a question please provide all the elements that a person who is willing to help will need to understand and effectively answer it.

Side notes to your code:

- `mkdir` is not necessary, WordPress handles this
- don't hardcode the path or URL of `wp-content`, you can use the constants [WP_CONTENT_DIR and WP_CONTENT_URL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_wp-content)

Best regards and good luck!