# Organize uploads by year, month and day

Tags: uploads

As of now my uploaded files are organized by year and month.  But I would like to organize them by year, month and day.  I mean like this `2012/10/30/image goes here`

PS: There is a [plugin available](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-upload-dir/screenshots/) to do this. But I don't want to use a plugin for this simple task. Thanks

Comment: @kaiser Sorry.. Corrected it.. I'm not going to use the code in my theme functions but going to use it in my mu-plugins.

Comment: I already corrected that for you (it's the other way 'round ;) ) - rolled back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code based in other [Answer of mine](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/53895/12615) and this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5489779/1287812).

It uses the post/page/cpt publish date to build the paths.
Note that `$the_post->post_date_gmt` is also available.

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'wpse_70946_handle_upload_prefilter');
add_filter('wp_handle_upload', 'wpse_70946_handle_upload');

function wpse_70946_handle_upload_prefilter( $file )
{
    add_filter('upload_dir', 'wpse_70946_custom_upload_dir');
    return $file;
}

function wpse_70946_handle_upload( $fileinfo )
{
    remove_filter('upload_dir', 'wpse_70946_custom_upload_dir');
    return $fileinfo;
}

function wpse_70946_custom_upload_dir($path)
{   
    /*
     * Determines if uploading from inside a post/page/cpt - if not, default Upload folder is used
     */
    $use_default_dir = ( isset($_REQUEST['post_id'] ) && $_REQUEST['post_id'] == 0 ) ? true : false; 
    if( !empty( $path['error'] ) || $use_default_dir )
        return $path; // Error: not uploading from a post/page/cpt 

    $the_post = get_post( $_REQUEST['post_id'] );
    $y = date( 'Y', strtotime( $the_post->post_date ) );
    $m = date( 'm', strtotime( $the_post->post_date ) );
    $d = date( 'd', strtotime( $the_post->post_date ) );

    $customdir = '/' . $y . '/' . $m . '/' . $d;

    $path['path']    = str_replace($path['subdir'], '', $path['path']); //remove default subdir (year/month)
    $path['url']     = str_replace($path['subdir'], '', $path['url']);      
    $path['subdir']  = $customdir;
    $path['path']   .= $customdir; 
    $path['url']    .= $customdir;  

    return $path;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the code. But its not working in my site. I'm using the magic field plugin for custom fields. This plugin handles my image uploads. It uses [wp_upload_dir() function](https://github.com/mistergiri/Magic-Fields-2/blob/fork/mf_constants.php) to store the images. Right now my image uploads are organized by year and month. I'm using your code in my mu-plugins folder. But when I upload a file its still not using day folder. Its not at all creating day folder. Am i missing something?  Do i have to uncheck "Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders" in media settings?

Comment: If the plugin "handles the image uploads", maybe we have a conflict of interests here... Can you post the relevant code it uses for that?

Comment: Please Note line number 19,30,31 of [this file](https://github.com/mistergiri/Magic-Fields-2/blob/fork/mf_constants.php) and line 86,87 of [this file](https://github.com/mistergiri/Magic-Fields-2/blob/fork/admin/mf_upload.php).   The second one has the main upload function of that plugin. Thanks

Comment: At a first glance, I don't see a way to surpass those plugin constants... I doubt, but try to give a late priority to the hooks, i.e., `add_filter('wp_handle_upload', 'wpse_70946_handle_upload', 9999 );`. :::: This code works for me in TwentyEleven without any active plugins and with Media Settings "Organize my uploads..." checked/unchecked. :::: If the code works for you without Magic Fields being active, then I guess you'll need to open a new Question or a support request... :/

Comment: Ok Thanks.. I'll give it a try. And one more weird thing. As i said earlier I put your code in my mu-plugins folder. My server time now is 00:44 Nov 1. I see some new folders 1970/01/01 and my existing image links are broken. Any idea?

Comment: Mu-plugins is quite early for some type of hooks. Try a regular plugin or even `functions.php`. In my tests, I checked the old uploads and their links were not affected. :::::::::: I don't see no reason for this code to break anything. I just opened a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/6294/uploads-folder?tab=general) if you'd like to debug this.

Comment: Hello mate. I found an alternative way using your code. I used this part of code `$d = date( 'd', strtotime( $the_post->post_date ) );` in magic field plugin. I mean I replaced the 16th line of [this file](https://github.com/mistergiri/Magic-Fields-2/blob/fork/mf_constants.php). So now it's creating a date folder instead of files_mf folder. I think it's not a perfect solution. But if I face any problem i'll ask you. Thanks for your time... Have a nice day...

Comment: I know that this is an old answer, but how would you update the old images to have the new file placements and update the uris in the db aswell?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, the filter 'upload_dir' is only called once in wp-includes\functions.php

I find this solution to be much simpler. It will place all uploads into the year/month/day directory for the date it is uploaded.

```
function upload_dir_filter($uploads){
    $day = date('d');
    $uploads['path'] .= '/' . $day;
    $uploads['url']  .= '/' . $day;
    return $uploads;
}
add_filter('upload_dir', 'upload_dir_filter');
```

Comment: Should probably use `wp_date` instead.

Comment: Shouldn't `$uploads['subdir']` be set as well?

Answer (score 0):

I have made a new code out of these 2 code. The images will be uploaded to the post date folder not the uploaded date folder:

```
function upload_dir_filter($uploads){

    $the_post = get_post( $_REQUEST['post_id'] );
    $y = date( 'Y', strtotime( $the_post->post_date ) );
    $m = date( 'm', strtotime( $the_post->post_date ) );
    $day = date( 'd', strtotime( $the_post->post_date ) );
    $uploads['path'] .= '/' . $day;
    $uploads['url']  .= '/' . $day;
    return $uploads;
}
add_filter('upload_dir', 'upload_dir_filter');
```