# make default upload folder year/month/day wordpress without plugin

Tags: uploads

is there any way to change in code and make it when you click(enable) “Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders. ” it to be default year/month/day ……… without any plugin.. Can anyone find for this solution please..?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

[Here is](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/70946/organize-uploads-by-year-month-and-day) a similar question.

The simplest solution that worked for me was use the `upload_dir` filter. Place the code below in your `functions.php` file.

```
function wpcb_upload_dir_filter($uploads){
    $day = date('d');
    $uploads['path'] .= '/' . $day;
    $uploads['url']  .= '/' . $day;
    return $uploads;
}
add_filter('upload_dir', 'wpcb_upload_dir_filter');
```

Comment: Just dropping by to say this works better than other solutions. This also handles uploads via the REST api