# How to use getimagesize() of image upload?

Tags: images, uploads

I need to check the resolution of an image I want to upload via media box, and then upload it into a custom directory.

As a starting point I used part of the code from [How Can I Organize the Uploads Folder by Slug (or ID, or FileType, or Author)?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25894/how-can-i-organize-the-uploads-folder-by-slug-or-id-or-filetype-or-author/53895#53895)

And a part of it looks like this:

```
function wpse_25894_custom_upload_dir($path)
{   

    $use_default_dir = ( isset($_REQUEST['post_id'] ) && $_REQUEST['post_id'] == 0 ) ? true : false; 
    if( !empty( $path['error'] ) || $use_default_dir )
        return $path; //error or uploading not from a post/page/cpt 

    //THIS LINE PRODUCE ERROR. HERE I NEED TO GET WIDTH AND HEIGHT OF IMAGE I WANT TO UPLOAD
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($path.'/'.$_POST['name']); 
    $customdir = '/'.$width.'x'.$height; //uplaod folder will be for example '640x480'

    $path['path']    = str_replace($path['subdir'], '', $path['path']); //remove default subdir (year/month)
    $path['url']     = str_replace($path['subdir'], '', $path['url']);      
    $path['subdir']  = $customdir;
    $path['path']   .= $customdir; 
    $path['url']    .= $customdir;  

    return $path;
}
```

`$_POST['name']` contains file name of image, like 'myimage.jpg'.

Comment: what is the status of this question, is it still unsolved?

Answer (score 1):

In this part:

```
getimagesize($path.'/'.$_POST['name']);
```

the variable `$path` is an array. Try to use

```
getimagesize($path['path'].'/'.$_POST['name']);
```

instead.